# access class in same module but in different file

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following code in the following two files:

**ClassA.ts**

```
module App {
    class ClassA{
    }
}
```

**ClassB.ts**

```
module App {
    export class ClassB{
        constructor(public ClassA) {}
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make ClassA accessible to classB ***without*** adding an `export` to ClassA? In other words, I want ClassA to only be accessible within the `App` module, but I also want to keep my classes in separate files.

Even when the compilation is output to a single file ClassA cannot access ClassB without the export.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this. Non-exported variables in modules are generated as locals in the module closure, so they're not visible at all outside the module block itself.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a way to do this since I do not want the classes to be accessible outside the module but I do want them to be able to interact and I also want them to be in separate files.